# Call a new class from an activity using Intent

Tags: android, class

I have created two classes in an Activity in android. How do I call the second class from the first class using Intent?

Comment: ....is the second class an Activity (or any other Android app component)? Because if it isn't, there is no point in using an Intent to communicate between them.

Comment: Yeah it displays a TextView

Comment: @aditya: You are calling java classes with Intent why?. Only three android component  (activity, service and broadcast receiver start with Intent).Have u read activity documentation.Please go through http://developer.android.com/index.html for study basic component of  android and should have basic knowledge about java.

Comment: Show us your code please

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
 startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: That will not work because using application context requires FLAG_NEW_ACTIVITY to start a new activity

Answer (score 0):

Intents are used to start an `Activity` from another `Activity` like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, Next.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

you can also use the bundle to pass on some `Data`

```
Intent intent=new Intent(StartActivity.this,Next.class);
                 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();   
                 bundle.putString( "nameValue",nameValue);  
                 bundle.putInt("value",variableName);
                 intent.putExtras(bundle);   
                 startActivity(intent);
```